# Puppet: reference count for resources and installing/dropping them on demand?

Tags: puppet

Still trying to get puppet to "do what I want" (I still don't know how to talk to it properly)...

I have the following problem: an Apache server hosts the static content for several clients, and this static content is versioned:

```
node the.node.name {
    client { 'c1':
        version => 'v1',
        # otherstuff
    }
    client { 'c2':
        version => 'v2',
    }
}
```

There are 30+ clients defined this way. And in total, there are between 2 and 4 versions of the content installed at any time.

Now, with time, the versions evolve -- quite rapidly. Right now I can only achieve to install new content, but never remove obsolete content.

How would you go about having reference counting for installed versions, and uninstall obsolete versions?

Comment: What sort of resources are c1 and c2? Are they rpm/deb packages, tar files, directories you're rsyncing, etc? This will affect the solutions available.

Comment: c1 and c2 are just "names". v1 and v2 are, at the moment, RPM versions. But I am not constrained to RPM in any way: _I_ control what format the resource is, it can be anything else, as long as I can make puppet manage it

Answer (score 1):

Store your static content in a git repository. Create a branch for each version of content that you want. Use puppet to create a repository if there isn't one, to ensure the correct branch is checked out, and to automatically update the repository. Git will take care of adding and removing files from there. Repoint your branches to whatever revision is appropriate at any given time.

Alternately, you might find that rsync with the proper flags (delete files not present on the master) might also work.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution could be though there is management overhead in adding and removing packages.

```
  package { 'c1_v8': ensure => present, }
  package { 'c2_v7': ensure => present, }

  package { 'c1_v1': ensure => absent, }
  package { 'c2_v2': ensure => absent, }
```

You could get fancier by using an external data source like hiera w/ puppet-hiera to manage which packages should be on which servers.

Comment: Well, here, the external sources are two, at a minimum: the RPM database (whether managed by `yum` or `rpm`) holds version information, and the "puppet database" knows which versions I want at a given moment. Trouble is, none of them is stateful. And here I need to know the state at step n-1 before the decision is made.